# Text Font and Colors in Visual Studio 2013 - Can't remove white border on the selected area

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I am having a tough time trying to remove the white border in my Visual Studio theme, the border is on the selected area.

[image]

Comment: No, its a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In playing around with Font and Colors Options it looks like `Highlight Current Line (Active)` the Item foreground setting is the one you need to change.  You get to it by going to Tools --> Options --> Fonts and Colors.

This is what it is set to on my dark theme.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!!  This has been the most annoying thing EVER!  I have been checking back to this post at least every 10 minutes.

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad I was able help, I had to play with the settings to find the right one, but I can see why it would be extremely annoying.